# cancelled Windows login turns off the display

Tags: windows, display, windows-11, power-management

***tl;dr*** a screen saver takes over but if I bump the mouse and then cancel the login, the screen/display turns off immediately. I would like the cancelled login to resume the screen saver.

My Windows 11 PC has *Power* settings

- *When plugged in, turn off my screen after **1 hour***
- *When plugged in, put my device to sleep after **Never***

[image: When plugged in, turn off my screen after 1 hour]

and *Screen Saver Settings*

- *Wait **10 minutes***
- [x] *On resume, display the logon screen*

[image: On resume, display the logon screen]

1. If I wait 10 minutes the screen saver takes over (expected).
2. When I press a key or wiggle the mouse, a login screen is presented (expected).
3. If I click cancel to login, or wait about 1 minute and let the login screen will cancel itself, then the display monitor turns off (unexpected).

***What setting should be adjusted so cancelling a login resumes the screen saver (and does not turn off the display monitor)?***

Comment: What happens if you let the screen go black instead of using a screen saver?  Any of my machines:  if I jar the mouse I can get to login.  If I do not login, the monitor goes back to black. It never turns Off.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @John . I tried using the _Blank_ screen saver but the same problem occurred; the display turned off after the login screen timed out.

Comment: Try without screen saver. Just let the monitor go dark when it has no signal.  LCD / LED monitors just go black without a signal.  Turn your screen saver off

Comment: @John I know I could turn off the screen saver but that's not what I want to do, hence this Question.

Comment: Your screen saver may be conflicting with the screen power management. That is why I stopped using screen savers when LCD screens came out some decades ago. No issues the way I do it.